Polars schema type casting using Numpy not implemented?
I'm trying to learn about polars, and I'm reading through the documentation. I'm starting with
LazyFrames and tinkering about schemas.
I've noticed that the type casting on a schema and pl.Series does not seem to work when using numpy types. However, it seems to still be  included in the official guide and documentation of polars.
I'm using version polars 0.20.5.
Examples.
pl.LazyFrame Schema.
pl.LazyFrame(data, schema=[
    ('a', pl.Float32),
    ('b', np.int64)
])

ValueError: cannot infer dtype from <class 'numpy.int64'> (type: 'type')

pl.Series dtype.
series_1 = pl.Series('a', [1, 2], dtype=pl.Float32)
series_2 = pl.Series('a', [1, 2], dtype=np.int64)

ValueError: given dtype: <class 'numpy.int64'> is not a valid Polars data type and cannot be converted into one


Do you have a link to where exactly you see this in the documentation?

Polars has its own type definitions. You must use those when casting in Polars. So that would bet pl.Float32, pl.Int64, pl.String, pl.List(pl.Boolean) etc.
We don't support numpy types and I also don't think we should. Polars is not numpy.
If you found this in the docs, can you post the link? We should remove that.

I think you're mixing up a few terms.
Type casting refers to converting one data type into another. For example converting an integer into a float or converting an 8 bit integer into a 16 bit integer.
Numpy and polars have very good interoperability and polars is able to infer dtypes from numpy arrays.
What polars doesn't do is treat the numpy class of a dtype as the same thing as its own.
Here's an example
# Create a numpy array with a specified dtype
numpy_array=np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.int64)

# Convert that into a polars Series
polars_series=pl.Series(numpy_array)

# Get its dtype
print(polars_series.dtype)
# Int64

# check if they're the same
polars_series.dtype==numpy_array.dtype
# False

So, while polars can infer the appropriate dtype when converting from a numpy array into a polars series (or dataframe) and vice versa, when entering the dtype parameter of a Polars method or defining a schema, you must use the Polars dtype. The numpy dtype is not interchangeable.
